# How to group date by week in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have pretty simple table which has 2 column. First one show time (`timestamp`), the second one show speed of car at that time (`float8`).

```
|      DATE_TIME      | SPEED |
|---------------------|-------|
| 2018-11-09 00:00:00 | 256   |
| 2018-11-09 01:00:00 | 659   |
| 2018-11-09 02:00:00 | 256   |
|      other dates    | xxx   |
| 2018-11-21 21:00:00 | 651   |
| 2018-11-21 22:00:00 | 515   |
| 2018-11-21 23:00:00 | 849   |
```

Lets say we have period from 9 november to 21 november. How to group that period by week. In fact I want such result:

```
|      DATE_TIME      | AVG_SPEED |
|---------------------|-----------|
| 9-11 November       | XXX       |
| 12-18 November      | YYY       |
| 19-21 November      | ZZZ       |
```

I use `PostgreSQL 10.4`.

I use such SQL Statement to know the number of the week of the certain date:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-11-09 00:00:00');
```

**EDIT**:

@tim-biegeleisen when I set period from '`2018-11-01`' to '`2018-11-13`' your sql statement return 2 result:

[image]

In fact I need such result:

```
2018-11-01 00:00:00 | 2018-11-04 23:00:00
2018-11-05 00:00:00 | 2018-11-11 23:00:00
2018-11-12 00:00:00 | 2018-11-13 05:00:00
```

As you can see in the calendar there are 3 week in that period.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this using a calendar table.  This answer assumes that a week begins with the first date in your data set.  You could also do this assuming something else, e.g. a standard week according to something else.

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('day', dd)::date AS dt
    FROM generate_series
    ( '2018-11-09'::timestamp 
    , '2018-11-21'::timestamp
    , '1 day'::interval) dd
),
cte AS (
    SELECT t1.dt, t2.DATE_TIME, t2.SPEED,
        EXTRACT(week from t1.dt) week
    FROM dates t1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.dt = t2.DATE_TIME::date
)

SELECT
    MIN(dt)::text || '-' || MAX(dt) AS DATE_TIME,
    AVG(SPEED) AS AVG_SPEED
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    week
ORDER BY
    MIN(dt);
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you check my post again pls. I test your sql statement and add more details about your sql statement but I need another result. I need something like `EXTRACT(WEEK from DATE_TIME)` but for several dates. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Thank your for your answer. That's what I need. Can you update your code in yout post with new one? Can I ask you one more question?! How to use `ORDER BY` in `EXTRACT`. Right now result is unsorted.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek My code has already been updated, except for the `ORDER BY` clause which I just added.  Use `ORDER BY MIN(dt)`.

Comment: I mean code inside stackoverflow. Change `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t1.dt) dr` to `EXTRACT(week from t1.dt) week`. You change sql statement only in `dbfiddle.uk`. In the future link could be unavailable.

Comment: I notice that `ORDER BY MIN(dt)` and `ORDER BY MAX(dt)` return the same result. What do you think about that?

Comment: I don't think much about that, because both the min and max are ordered the same way.  Therefore, we may order using either one.